# Website does not rotate with ipad, stays on its side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ipad, responsive-design

For some reason, my webpage does not stay in correct position when you flip the ipad. Please see google page attached image example (of course, google works, just take it as an example.)

My website looks nice when the ipad is in horizontal position. But looks on its side when it is in vertical position.

I'm using bootstrap 3.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Can you link your site?

Comment: You don't have the orientation locked on the iPad, right?

Comment: No. Other websites work fine.